# SQL Server 2016: How to remove records that are NOT duplicates but have duplicate values?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I'm new here and relatively new to SQL. I have a table similar to this:

```
[Pk], [Case_No], [Status], [Open_Date], [Close_Date], [Case_Age], [Report_Date]
```

Every week, all cases, open or closed, are dumped into the table with a new report date.  What I want to do is be able to remove the records that are reoccurring that have already been closed. I want to keep the first instance where the case was reported as closed, but I don't need the duplicates (unless the case is still open.)  I hope this makes since...it has been a long day.  I already have a solution going forward, but I need to clean up historical records to report correctly.

If i could figure out how to add a flag or something...I have tried `Dense_Rank()`, but I don't want the null close dates ranked...

I have googled for ideas for days and I am now turning to the experts for suggestions. Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using a [common table expression (cte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
            partition by Case_No, [Status]
            order by Report_Date asc
            )
  from t
  where [Status] = 'Closed'  
)
select *
from cte
where rn > 1
```

To delete them, just change `select *` to `delete`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! You have made my day!